# Where put web elements in cucumber steps?

Tags: javascript, cucumber, webdriver-io, gherkin

I learn to write cucumber wdio test. In my project also I use page object pattern.
This is my step, where I click for subcategory Camera and photos from headerComponent page:

```
When('User clicks {string}', async function () {
  await homePage.clickElement(headerComponent.subcategoryCamerasAndPhotos);
});
```

But I need to write universal step with click for many elements. I should put element as parameters. How can I do this?

I need something like this, but I don't know where put my web element:

```
When('User clicks {string}', async function (element) {
  await homePage.clickElement(element);
});
```